# QL - Grouping sales data by month sold - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am looking at a different aspect of the sales dashboard I am working on;

The relevant items in the queried dataset are as follows:

`Invoice Date`, `Margin Amount`

I wanted to get output such as:

```
                     2012            2013
January              $0             $0   
February             $0             $0   
March                $0             $0   
April                $0             $0   
May                  $0             $0   
June                 $0             $40   
July                 $0             $40   
August               $0             $0   
September            $0             $0   
October              $0             $40   
November             $0             $0   
December             $0             $0
```

Sample Data: (Irrelevant fields not included)

```
Invoice Date     Margin Amount
2013-06-27       40
2013-07-29       40
2013-10-30       40
```

I also made a table listing the `start date` and `end date` of each month. Fields are as follows;

```
Month Year Start_Date End_Date
January 2000 01/01/2000 31/01/2000
February 2000 01/02/2000 28/02/2000
```

All the way up until December 2016, if it helps...

I was hoping that all Margin fields could be added together - When I say summed up, I mean all the transactions that occurred in January would be added together (So in the output table, next to January and under 2010 would be January 2010's total margin amount). Each transaction has a margin field and a date.

Would greatly appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Are we supposed to guess how you got your monthly numbers?

Comment: Made the sample data a little clearer. The numbers are just stored as Margin Amount in a table and are not caluclated

Comment: How flexible do you need it? Just two years: current and previous?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Hi PM,

Ideally I would like to have it with the ability to flex for the whole set of data up to around 2015. I have a date table as well which starts from January 2000 up to December 2016 defined in another table called Month but unsure if this can be used

    Month  Start Date   End Date
    January 1/1/2000    31/01/2000
etc

Comment: I have tried various sum commands with group by clauses but didn't save it sorry. Its probably a simple problem but my brain just isn't working today :(

Comment: Yes, your `Month` table will be useful, you may want to add it to your post.

Comment: As long as you have fixed number of predefined years, all you need is to LEFT JOIN Month to main table ON year + month. Then create `CASE- WHEN-END` column for each year and GROUP BY by year, month. Alternatively you can use PIVOT.

Comment: select sum(Margin Amount) from Sales.All 
join Dates on Sales.Invoice Date between Dates.[Start Date] and Dates.[End Date] group by Month,Year

Not having much luck though, I suspect I am doing something wrong

Comment: Join to your calendar table to map dates to months/ years. Then display your crosstab in your dashboard tool - don't do it in a SQL query. What is your dashboard tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following does what you're after.  I used the years 2011 through 2015.  The first bit fakes input tables with a series of CTEs.  You'll replace these with your actual data.  The query aggregates margin by month/year and then uses a PIVOT query to transform each year into horizontal columns.

Edit:  Code has been edited to work with SqlFiddle OP posted.

```
WITH 
months AS (SELECT 1 AS mon UNION ALL SELECT mon + 1 FROM months WHERE mon < 12),
years AS (SELECT 2011 AS yr UNION ALL SELECT yr + 1 FROM years WHERE yr < 2015)

-- End data setup, real work begins here
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT 
    months.mon, years.yr, COALESCE(SUM(inv.[Margin Amount]), 0) AS MarginAmount
FROM 
    months
    CROSS JOIN years 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN All1 inv ON ( (YEAR(inv.[Invoice Date]) = years.yr) AND (MONTH(inv.[Invoice Date]) = months.mon) )
GROUP BY 
    months.mon, years.yr 
) AS source 
PIVOT
(
    MAX(MarginAmount)
    FOR yr in ([2011], [2012], [2013], [2014], [2015])
)
AS pvt  
ORDER BY mon
```

Comment: This gives me a great format for the report but unfortunately it is not gathering the information contained in the table called All (i.e [All].[Invoice Amount].

The output is exactly what I had in mind, but I was hoping tog et the invoice $ plugging into the table

Comment: Invoice amount wasn't shown in your sample data, so I didn't know.  Are you wanting the invoice amount in addition to the margin, instead of the margin, or summed with the margin?

Comment: Sorry I meant Margin Amount in that last post rather than Invoice Amount. Let me try again;

The sample data I put in the first post is just an idea of the style of data in a table called "All". The years are in a separate table called "Dates". Within the table "All" are hundreds on hundreds of transactions - I was hoping to sum them together being grouped by the month in which they occurred - so just like the demo output from the first post but with the actual Margin Amount being calculated there

Comment: When you say "sum them together" what does that mean?  Margin + some field you haven't mentioned here?  Update your question to better reflect your schema and expected output but it shouldn't be hard for you to adapt the solution I gave here to your needs.

Comment: Hi Dazed,

I apologise for being unclear. I was hoping that all Margin fields could be added together and summed up in the format that your code sets up. When I say summed up, I mean all the transactions that occurred in January would be added together (So in the output table, next to January and under 2010 would be January 2010's total margin amount). Each transaction has a margin field and a date.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, that is exactly what the code I provided does.  Did you try it?  What result did it give vs. what you were expecting?

Comment: I tried it but I only got the 3 sets of $40 defined in the set up part of your code. I would have expected to see summary data for the relevant months. I think it may have something to do with the tables - e.g I can't see a reference to the table called 'All' which has the 'Invoice Amount' column in it.

Comment: Of course that's all you'll get... I had to mock test data so that I could test the code.  You will have to make the necessary adjustments to make it compatible with your schema.  Where I'm referencing a table called Invoice it sounds like you need to change it to All.  Also, you keep referencing a column called "Invoice Amount" in your comments but you've told me you want to sum a column called margin.

Comment: Hi Dazed,Sorry I am working on a few projects at once and keep mixing these columns up. It is actually called 'Margin Amount'. Invoice Amount is a column in the dataset. I have set up an SQL fiddle - Could you have a look and see if you can make it function? I have taken real data from the database for this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9d79e/1   (Had to call the table All1 as All appears to be a reserved name)

Comment: My answer has been updated.  The code now works with your fiddle.

Comment: OH my god, you are amazing Dazed! Thank you so very very much!

Comment: Is there any way to make it say January, Feburary etc rather than 1,2,3,4?